# наименование html элементов. БЭМ

Tags: html, css, бэм

**Микс**

Прием, позволяющий использовать разные БЭМ-сущности на одном DOM-узле.

Миксы позволяют:

- совмещать поведение и стили нескольких сущностей без дублирования кода;
- Элемент списка

```html
<!-- Блок `header` -->
<div class="header">
  <!-- К блоку `search-form` примиксован элемент `search-form` блока `header`-->
  <div class="search-form header__search-form"></div>
</div>
```

**Источник:** [Быстрый старт - Микс](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81).

У меня есть блок `header`. Внутри него есть меню `nav` и дочерние элементы `nav__item`, `nav__link`. Мне необходимо изменить стили у навигации, и для этого я добавил классы: `header__nav`, `header__item`, `header__link`. Вопрос заключается в том, что в блоке `header` могут быть и другие ссылки, но они будут иметь другие стили и назвать их `header__link` будет не уместно, а стили писать через основной родительский класс тоже плохо, ибо они будут повторяться в другом месте, но будут иметь другие стили.

```html
<body class="page">
  <header id="home" class="header page__header">
    <nav class="nav header__nav">
      <li class="nav__item header__item">
        <a href="#home" class="nav__link header__link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item header__item">
        <a href="#about" class="nav__link header__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item header__item">
        <a href="#works" class="nav__link header__link">Works</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Раньше я просто писал класс, на основе класса родителя: `header-nav`, но это мешает повторно использовать блок.

```html
<body class="page">
  <header id="home" class="header page__header">
    <nav class="header-nav header__nav">
      <li class="header-nav__item">
        <a href="#home" class="header-nav__link header-nav__link_active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-nav__item">
        <a href="#about" class="header-nav__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-nav__item">
        <a href="#works" class="header-nav__link">Works</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

P.S: У меня был вариант дать второй класс - блок, но я не знаю на сколько это адекватно.

```html
<body class="page">
  <header id="home" class="header page__header">
    <nav class="nav header-nav">
      <li class="nav__item header-nav__item">
        <a href="#home" class="nav__link header-nav__link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item header-nav__item">
        <a href="#about" class="nav__link header-nav__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item header-nav__item">
        <a href="#works" class="nav__link header-nav__link">Works</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: сколько у вас блоков `.nav` на всём сайте?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, на моем сайте только в header, но этот вопрос на будущее. Допустим это будет header, main, footer.

Comment: на мой взгляд, не стоит использовать использовать один блок `.nav` для всех меню на сайте. Они как правило слишком разные.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, абстрагируйтесь. это просто пример. пускай это будет что - то другое. важная идея, и то как ее реализовать.

Comment: Зачем вам задавать `header__item` или `header__link`?
Если у вас есть `nav` и элементы от этого блока которые вы стилизируете, а через `header__nav` позиционируете. Абсолютно универсальное решение для всего у вас вряд ли получится, покрайней мере я пытался и не смог. Поэтому сначала смотрю на задачу.

Comment: @E_K, я же уже объяснил, что может быть такое, что в header будут и другие ссылки, и необходимо понять как правильно писать классы. Сделать второй класс-блок к примеру, как я выше указал, но я не знаю на сколько это верное решение.

Comment: Если вам нужно изменить стиль для другого блока nav с ссылками используйте модификаторы, зачем именно всем ссылкам в  header задавать класс header__link?

Comment: @E_K, а какой класс-модификатор нужно использовать? nav__link является элементом nav. для nav я делаю модификатор header__nav, а ссылкам какой делать, что бы он был универсальным, и мог другим ссылкам в блоке header дать другой модификатор?

Comment: `header__nav` это элемент `header`, а не модификатор. Как пример задайте nav доп. класс `nav--theme_light`, а после используйте селектор `nav--theme_light nav__link`

Comment: @E_K, Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86900/discussion-between---and-e-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется в данном случае более гибким решением будет [модификатор ключ-значение](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/block-modification/#%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

```html
<body class="page">
  <header id="home" class="header page__header">
    <nav class="nav nav_theme_ligth">
      <li class="nav__item nav__item_theme_ligth">
        <a href="#home" class="nav__link nav__link_theme_ligth">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item nav__item_theme_ligth">
        <a href="#about" class="nav__link nav__link_theme_ligth">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item nav__item_theme_ligth">
        <a href="#works" class="nav__link nav__link_theme_ligth">Works</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Это позволит не только переиспользовать ваш код, но и не привязываться к контексту. 
Обратите внимание, что можно использовать любое количество таких модификаторов, например: "*nav__item nav__item_theme_ligth nav__item_direction_right nav__item_active*"

Comment: по поводу модификаторов уже был разговор, но проблема в наименовании. если использовать theme, то по сути все элементы будут иметь этот префикс. еще момент в том, что стили могут быть не под тему, а универсальными для каждого меню, и тут встает вопрос в том, как правильно использовать имя, ибо модификатор характеризует внешний вид, но как я выше сказал, он индивидуальный может быть.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Вы не до конца поняли как работать с модификаторами поэтому надумали себе проблему. theme это всего лишь пример, но даже если использовать theme вам ничего не мешает использовать на разных элементах разные темы. Вот вам еще пример: Одна ссылка может быть nav__item_direction_right, а другая nav__item_direction_left и обе они могут миксоваться с другими модификаторами отвечающими за поведение, структуру и состояние

Comment: я ничего не надумывал, а лишь попросил пример наименования. допустим 
ссылка навигации в другом блоке будем иметь другой размер текста, паддинг и тд, и мне не понятно как я должен назвать.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный поэтому я вам и пытаюсь объяснить на примерах.  Если вы хотите изменить стиль, то можете назвать nav__item_style_header, но лучше не header а что-то более абстрактное вплоть до цифр nav__item_style_1 но так будет менее понятно. В общем значение у ключа должно помочь вам понять, что именно делает этот модификатор. И обратите внимание это очень важно понять, style_header это не один модификатор это пара ключ-значение style-это ключ, а header в данном случае его значение никак не связанное с контекстом